# How can I check if a modal view is currently over my self.window.rootViewController?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I need to check if there is still a modal view over the root view controller.
The problem I am facing is that I have a second modal view coming from some thread that needs to be displayed. I want to delay the second modal view until the first one is gone.
I cannot just launch it after the first is dismissed because the second modal view is conditional.

```
[self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

What I want to do (feel free to suggest a better alternative way):

1. Check if `self.window.rootViewController` currently has a modal view displayed on top (or is still animating modal view).
2. use `performSelector:afterDelay:0.1`
3. Check again, and if needed, delay again

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Get `rootViewController.presentedViewController` (available in iOS 5.0+) or `rootViewController.modalViewController` (available in iOS 2.0+) and see if it's nil.

Also, you **don't** want to present the second view controller from the secondary thread, all UI stuff **has** to be done on the main thread.

Comment: This is ok right? "                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    MedicationReminderViewController *vc = [[MedicationReminderViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MedicationReminderViewController" bundle:nil];
[theDelegate.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
                });"

Comment: @Pieter, This is fine, yes, this code will be executed on the main thread

Comment: I suppose that rootViewController.modalViewController is any modalViewController that is displayed modally on top of rootViewController?

Comment: From the docs: `modalViewController` is the controller for the active presented view — that is, the view that is temporarily displayed on top of the view managed by the receiver. `presentedViewController` is the view controller that is presented by this view controller, or one of its ancestors in the view controller hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this kind of problem. I wanted to pop up a modal from push and before I do that I wanted to check if some screen is already presented and if yes dismiss those and pop my screen below is the code.

```
    // Dismiss all the modals which are currently shown.
    - (void) dismissAllModalsIfAnyWithCompletion:(void(^)(BOOL success)) completion{

            BOOL hiddenByModal = nil != [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController presentedViewController];
        if (hiddenByModal) {
//We need to dismiss the existing modal and after completion pop up the new modal.
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
                // After dismissing let the handler know.
                completion(YES);
            }];
        }
        else{
// If there is no modal, then simply let the handler know to pop the new modal.
            completion(YES);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nice elegant solution. (Although the BOOL flag seems a bit overly complex. Why not just do `if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController presentedViewController])`?)

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to do something a bit more deterministic.  Have one piece of code responsible for doing both modal displays and let it keep track of when the first modal appears and disappears so that, if it receives a message to display the second one, it knows whether to do it or just set a "pending" flag.  When it is told that the first one has been dismissed, it can check whether a second is pending.